# C# Namegenarator brings 5 same letters

Tags: c#, string, generator

I write a little namegenerator. I always test it with count 5(brings me a name with 5 letters ^^)
Now the problem is that the programm brings me always the same 5 letters. Like GGGGG or HHHHH.
The magic is that if i go step by step with the debugger it works as it must.

Today im on my phone but i try to bring the code here tomorrow.
Maybe somebody can help me without the code.

Greetings
The bee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using a random generator (`System.Random`). And I guess you are initializing this generator inside the loop. In that case the solution would be: put the random outside the loop and initialize it once, only once.

If you initialize a random generator, it takes the current time as sime kind op "start position" to calculate new values. But if you iterate very fast through the loop and initialize the random generator 5 times at almost exact the same moment, they will produce the same results. If you go through the code step by step, of course more time will pass resulting in different results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Beginner fault :D